# jQuery Media Plugin doesnt works in firefox4

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, firefox4

I had used jquery media plugin to display pdf file in html

This is my following codes...

```
<head>
    <title>New document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery_media.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('a.media').media({width:500, height:400});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="media" href="check_pdf.pdf">PDF File</a>
</body>
```

My html file displays pdf file in all browser except ff4.

**Why Firefox4 doesnt display pdf file instead of displaying it throw out pdf file as download file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Adobe Reader plugin installed on FF4?

Even so there looks to be a bug http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/803288.

Best test - can you view other pdf files, from other sites in the FF4 browser?